# Why Beautifulsoup is getting weird source code characters while downloading a web-page?

Tags: python, html, unicode, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm new in python and web-crawling. I'm doing a few exercises crawling some web-sites and seems great with beautifulsoup. But recently, while I was crawling a Persian site (https://video.varzesh3.com) with the code below, I am receiving weird characters. I have done the same procedure on other Persian websites an I believe the problem is not with the encoding. This is my code:

```
url = 'https://video.varzesh3.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

And this is a part of the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<title>ÙÛØ¯ÛÙ ÙØ±Ø²Ø´ Ø³Ù | Ø®Ø§ÙÙ</title>
<meta content="sport ,varzesh ,football, soccer,livescores, live score, livescore, iran,football3,Daily soccer news , broadcast ,ÙÙØªØ¨Ø§Ù Ø³Ù , ÙØªØ§ÛØ¬ Ø²ÙØ¯Ù , Ø®ÙÛØ¬ ÙØ§Ø±Ø³ , perian gulf , ÙÛÚ¯ Ø¢Ø²Ø§Ø¯Ú¯Ø§Ù ,  ÙÙØ±ÙØ§ÙØ§Ù Ø¢Ø³ÛØ§ ,  ÙÙØ±ÙØ§ÙØ§Ù Ø§Ø±ÙÙ¾Ø§ ,  ÙÛÚ¯ Ø¨Ø±ØªØ± , Ø¬Ø§Ù Ø­Ø°ÙÛ , Ø´Ø¨Ú©Ù Ø³Ù , ÙØ±Ø²Ø´ , ÙÙØªØ¨Ø§Ù Ø¨Ø±ØªØ± , Ø§ÛØ±Ø§Ù , Ø¬Ø§Ù Ø¬ÙØ§ÙÛ , Ø¬Ø§Ù Ø¬ÙØ§ÙÛ 2010,ÙÙØªØ¨Ø§Ù 3 ," name="keywords">
<meta content="Ù¾Ø§ÙÚ¯Ø§Ù ÙÛØ¯ÛÙ ÙØ±Ø²Ø´Û Ø¨Ø±Ø§Ù ÙØ§Ø±Ø³Ù Ø²Ø¨Ø§ÙØ§Ù ÙÙ ÙÛØ¯ÛÙ Ø­ÙØ²Ù ÙØ±Ø²Ø´ (ÙÙØªØ¨Ø§ÙØÙØ§ÙÙØ¨Ø§Ù ØØ¨Ø³ÙØªØ¨Ø§Ù Ù...) Ø±Ø§ Ø§Ø±Ø§Ø¦Ù ÙÛ Ú©ÙØ¯" name="description">
<link href="/Static/css/frontend.min.css?v=9" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://static2.farakav.com/v3/static/css/fonts.css?version=6" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://static2.farakav.com/varzesh3/assets/font/varzesh3-icon/varzesh3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://static2.farakav.com/football3_jscripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Static/js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Static/js/mustache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        now = new Date();
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        var script_address = 'https://cdn.yektanet.com/js/varzesh3.com/article.v1.min.js';
        script.src = script_address + '?v=' + now.getFullYear().toString() + '0' + now.getMonth() + '0' + now.getDate() + '0' + now.getHours();
        head.appendChild(script);
    </script>
```

Why do I get this weird like "Ù¾Ø§ÙÚ¯Ø§Ù ÙÛØ¯ÛÙ ÙØ±Ø²Ø´Û Ø¨Ø±Ø§Ù ÙØ§Ø±Ø³" characters?

Answer (score 1):

You get those wired characters because of it's encoding.

```
>>> source_code.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
```

Try this, set encoding to `UTF-8`

```
>>> source_code.encoding = 'UTF-8'          
>>> plain_text = source_code.text
>>> BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
```

---

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<title>ویدیو ورزش سه | خانه</title>
<meta content="sport ,varzesh ,football, soccer,livescores, live score, livescore, iran,football3,Daily soccer news , broadcast ,فوتبال سه , نتایج زنده , خلیج فارس , perian gulf , لیگ آزادگان ,  قهرمانان آسیا ,  قهرمانان اروپا ,  لیگ برتر , جام حذفی , شبکه سه , ورزش , فوتبال برتر , ایران , جام جهانی , جام جهانی 2010,فوتبال 3 ," name="keywords">
<meta content="پايگاه ویدیو ورزشی براي فارسي زبانان كه ویدیو حوزه ورزش (فوتبال،واليبال ،بسكتبال و...) را ارائه می کند" name="description">
<link href="/Static/css/frontend.min.css?v=9" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
....
...
..
```